# Mysql get sub list with count

Tags: mysql, sql, select, group-by, pivot

I have table data in this form.

```
it w count
i1 a 2  
i1 b 3
i2 a 1
i3 c 2
i4 b 1
```

When I query for a-b pair for each item (it) and respective count. If certain item (it) doesn't have both a and b then it is ignored (like i3). I need output in the form

```
it a b 
i1 2 3
i2 1 0
i4 0 1
```

Any ideas how to solve this?
And I cannot store each word in different column. There are many words and mXn matrix of such a matrix is sparse.

Based on Saharsh's answer we could do it by

```
SELECT * FROM (SELECT a.it, SUM(CASE WHEN a.w = 'a' THEN a.count ELSE 0 END) AS a,
SUM(CASE WHEN a.w = 'b' THEN a.count ELSE 0 END) AS b 
FROM tableA a WHERE a.w IN ('a', 'b') GROUP BY a.it) WHERE a>0 OR b>0
```

Is there a better way it terms of handling data with million rows?

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with conditional aggregation:

```
select it, max(case when w = 'a' then count else 0 end) as a,
       max(case when w = 'b' then count else 0 end) as b
from table t
where w in ('a', 'b')
group by it;
```

Comment: Here the output includes i3 item as well.  BY returning empty values.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT a.it, 
       SUM(CASE WHEN a.w = 'a' THEN a.count ELSE 0 END) AS a, 
       SUM(CASE WHEN a.w = 'b' THEN a.count ELSE 0 END) AS b
FROM tableA a 
WHERE a.w IN ('a', 'b')
GROUP BY a.it;
```

Check this [**SQL FIDDLE DEMO**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/4defc8/1)

**OUTPUT**

```
| IT | A | B |
|----|---|---|
| i1 | 2 | 3 |
| i2 | 1 | 0 |
| i4 | 0 | 1 |
```

Comment: i3 item shuldn't be included in result set as both a,b doesn't exist. One way is by running query over this 

SELECT * FROM (SELECT a.it, 
       SUM(CASE WHEN a.w = 'a' THEN a.count ELSE 0 END) AS a, 
       SUM(CASE WHEN a.w = 'b' THEN a.count ELSE 0 END) AS b
FROM tableA a 
WHERE a.w IN ('a', 'b')
GROUP BY a.it) WHERE a>0 OR b>0 . Is there a better way?

Comment: @user2517372 there is no need to use sub query.you can directly fetch the records

Comment: @user2517372 Check the fiddle demo to verify the output